# md5 "%02x" fprintf

Tags: hash, md5, printf

I have to calculate md5 hash for a file. I succesfully find libraries to do it, and they print the hash on screen. 
I have to print the hash on a txt file, but I have some problems. It only prints 00 intead of the all 32 bit hash. This is the print function. I only add the lines to open the file and to print on it, the rest of the function is from the library and works fine, because on the screen the hash is printed in the right way.

Seems to be some kind of problems with fprintf and %02x". Thanks.

```
static void MDPrint (mdContext)
MD5_CTX *mdContext;
{
  int i;
  FILE *fp;
  if((fp=fopen("userDatabase.txt", "ab"))==NULL) printf("Error while opening the file..\n");
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            printf ("%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
            fprintf(fp, "%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
    }
fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here;

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf ("%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
```

Since there are no curly braces, only the printf line will be inside the loop. You need to add braces to make both lines be inside the loop;

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    printf ("%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
}
```